# How can I trigger api calls with async pipe on a value change in the service file in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

We have an application based on the Location. Once the user changes the Location drop down (in app component) I need to call all the dependent APIs in the sub components.

How can I achieve this RxJS operators ?

I tried something like this but couldn't get the expected results.
Expected on change of the Location with setLocation function getOutwardReturnableData$ | async is called in the other components where all its referenced.

```
selectedLocation: string = '';

setLocation(location: string) {
    this.selectedLocation = location;
}

get getOutwardReturnableData$(): Observable<IEntryOutwardReturnable> {
    // console.log("DataService -> getOutwardReturnableData", this.getOutwardReturnableData$);
    return this.http.post<IEntryOutwardReturnable>(
        endPointData.GetOutwardReturnablMatDet,
        { LocationID: this.selectedLocation }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the selectedLocation as a trigger for your api call. The flow (modification to that observable) can be defined inside the constructor or directly where you do the declaration.

```js
export class XYService {
  private selectedLocation$ = new Subject();
  outwardReturnable$: Observable<IEntryOutwardRegturnable>;

  constructor() {
    this.outwardReturnable$ = this.selectedLocation$.pipe(
      switchMap(LocationId => this.http.post<...>(endpoint, { LocationId })
    );
  }

  setLocation(location: string) {
    this.selectedLocation$.next(location);
  }
}
```

Here a new http request will be triggered if the selected location changes. The http request will have the data of the latest change made to the location. The `switchMap` also cancels pending http requests if new locations are arriving in a short amount of time.

You should also catch the errors properly using the `catchError` operator inside the switchMap. From here you can use the `outwardReturnable$` to read the data from the stream. To have an initial value inside the subject, you can use a `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: FYI: You do not need to define the observable in the constructor. You can define them straight away at initialization. This will allow you to see if something is used before declaration. Nevertheless the solution is fine :)

Comment: Agreed, thanks for your hint. It is personal preference because then you can keep a good immediate overview of the services interface. Disadvantage is it adds 2 extra lines of code. Mentioned that in the second sentence as well. :)

Comment: I have a video that goes through the above style code in detail. Would it be acceptable to post that here for the OPs reference?

Comment: Do you mean to create an additional post or should I include that video with your reference? I guess, you mean your excellent talk "data-composition with rxjs" from ng-conf '19?